# Como substituir dados de uma coluna por dados de outro dataframe usando condições comparativas?

Tags: python, pandas, loop

Estou tentando substituir os valores de uma coluna baseado em duas colunas de outro dataframe.

- O dataframeX que receberá a substituição possui uma coluna que é uma lista de municípios do Brasil.
- O dataframeY que vai ser utilizado contém a lista com todos os municípios do Brasil e seus respectivos estados.

Eu preciso que o dataframeX verifique se o municípioX é igual ao municípioY e substitua o valor do municipioX pelo estado do dataframeY. Eu estava tentando isso, mas a lógica está incorreta.

```
    for i in dfX['municipioX']:
       for x, y in (dfY['municipioY'], dfY['estado']):
           if i == x:
           dfX['municipio'][i] == y
```

Esse é o DataframeY:

| municipioY | estado |
| --- | --- |
| Campinas | São Paulo |
| Belém | Pará |

DataframeX antes da mudança:

| municipioX |
| --- |
| Campinas |
| Belém |

DataframeX depois da mudança:

| municipioX |
| --- |
| São Paulo |
| Pará |

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação [`pandas.DataFrame.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) junta colunas com outro [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) no índice ou em uma coluna de chave.

Não tem mistério junte `dfX` com `dfY` usando `municipioX` como chave em `dfX`, através do parâmetro `on` em `pandas.DataFrame.join()`, e defina `municipioY` como índice para `dfY`, usando [pandas.DataFrame.set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```
import pandas as pd

dfY = pd.DataFrame({
  'municipioY': ['Campinas', 'Belém'],
  'estado': ['São Paulo', 'Pará']
})

dfX = pd.DataFrame({
  'municipioX': ['Campinas', 'Belém', 'Campinas', 'Campinas', 'Belém', 'Taubaté']
})

#Junta dfX com dfY cruzando os dados da coluna dfX.municipioX com dfY.municipioY
dfX['municipioX'] = dfX.join(dfY.set_index('municipioY'), on='municipioX')['estado']

dfX
#  municipioX
#0  São Paulo
#1       Pará
#2  São Paulo
#3  São Paulo
#4       Pará
#5        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar a função [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)  .

```
dfX = dfX.mask((dfX['municipioX'] == dfY['municipioY']), other = dfY['estado'], axis=0)
```

Em geral deve-se evitar fazer iterações sobre o dataframe. Já exitem funções vetorizadas para quase todo tipo de manipulação que voce queria fazer, pesquise na documentação do pandas antes de partir para uma iteração. As funções vetorizadas tendem a ser mais eficientes, evitam-se alguns problemas e seu código fica mais compacto e fácil de ler/entender.

Comment: Seu exemplo gera erro `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: Você tem razão, me basei nos df´s da pergunta pra fazer o exemplo. Com dados mais genéricos nao vai funcionar.